# Working with attachments **to** a PDF file in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, attachments

I've got a PDF that has something else (actually, another PDF) as an attachment. Like most Mac users I use Preview by default to view PDFs, and Preview gives no indication that I can find that there is an attachment, nor can I figure out how to access the attachment now that I know it's there. I was pretty confused until I tried Adobe Reader which immediately makes it clear that there is an attachment. Am I missing something here or is Preview essentially ignoring attachments?

Comment: Preview is pretty *dumb* and does not recognize any "extra" feature which is recognized by other tools like Adobe.

Comment: @Rob - Other way round really… Adobe can do what they like with PDF & Apple has no obligation to keep up with their proprietary format. Google "The demise of Flash" for parallels.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately Preview does not support or indicate PDF attachments in a PDF, or any file Preview can open. I suggest you continue to use [Adobe Reader for Mac](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?platform=macintosh&product=10).

You can [send your feedback about this to Apple here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/).

Answer (score 5):

Preview doesn't support this, but you can extract attachments on the command line using the popper tool `pdfdetach`.  To install poppler with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install poppler
```

To list attachments in a PDF file called `doc.pdf`:

```
pdfdetach -list doc.pdf
```

To extract attachments from a PDF file called `doc.pdf`:

```
pdfdetach -saveall doc.pdf
```